# Plotting multiple store sales into 1 plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have problem plotting multiple timeseries into 1 plot.
My dataframe looks like this: 
[image]

So I want all 10 stores plotted into 1 plot, such that all stores have different colours, with the end product looking like this: 
[image]

So far I've tried with the foloowing code, but it does not work:

```
store_daily_sales = train.groupby(['store', 'date'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8), dpi = 150)
plt.plot(store_daily_sales)
plt.title = ('Daily sales') 
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.show()
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code/data. Format your dataframe in a way that makes it easy for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Upload the data file to Google and post the link here, without the data it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're best off reformatting a bit first and then plotting. Hopefully this does the trick:

```
reformat = pd.pivot(train,values='sales',index='date',columns='store')
reformat.plot()
```